# How to make Github Action be triggered by push events of another repositorie

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to automatically merge a repo to mine, if I cant't is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a GitHub Action that enables you to trigger workflows in your repository as soon as an event happens on another repository: https://github.com/convictional/trigger-workflow-and-wait

Here is a nice blog by the creator of the Action which documents on how you can use the Action effectively: https://keithweaver.ca/lessons/trigger-another-repositorys-github-action-workflow-wait-for-result